# Relative adverbs or relative pronouns

Tags: grammar

"The holiday season is here. This is a time when many of us plan to get away from it all. But what about **the home** that you are leaving behind?"

I want to know if I can use 'where' instead of 'that'? if not why we can't use relative adverbs like relative pronoun in every situation?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot substitute a relative adverb for a relative pronoun: it replaces ***preposition* + which**. For example,

> But what about the home **in which** you grew up?
>   But waht about the home **where** you grew up?

The ***preposition* + which** version tends to be used in more formal settings.

See [this link](http://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/relative-adverbs/) for more examples.

Comment: You mean I have to rewrite as: "But what about the home behind which you are leaving ?"  or "But what about the home where you are leaving ?"

Comment: @MickeyMouse: leave it as it is.  Why would you want to use **where** in this context? You are trying to insert a preposition where no preposition is required, and so both of the sentences that you have proposed don't make sense. If you really really want to use **where** in a sentence, start off with a sentence that requires (in/at) + which.

Comment: So whenever I wanted to substitute 'relative adverbs' for 'relative pronoun' put 'preposition+which' if it makes sense then we can use both of them ; otherwise we are only allowed to use 'relative pronoun.'

Comment: @MickeyMouse: relative pronouns and relative adverbs serve different purposes: it is unlikely that you will find a situation where you can replace a relative pronoun with preposition+which.

Comment: Sorry. I don't want to replace a relative pronoun with preposition +which. I want to replace relative adverbs with 'preposition + which'. Sorry If I couldn't tell what I meant. For example: I like to visit NY the city where I was born //// I like to visit NY the city in which I was born. where= in +which

Comment: @MickeyMouse: yes, that's fine then. Have a look at the link to see which relative adverb corresponds to which pronoun.

Comment: @MickeyMouse **(a)** 'Pronoun' is a misleading term: *which* and *who* don't stand for a noun but for an entire noun phrase (NP), so it would more accurately be called a 'pro-NP'. In the same way, *where* is a 'pro-PP'--it stands for a preposition phrase (PP). **(b)** In your *leaving behind* example, *home* is not the object of *behind*, but the direct object of *leave*; *behind* is an 'intransitive preposition' which acts as an entire preposition phrase without an object. Consequently bare *which* is appropriate here--*the home which you are leaving behind*--because it refers to the place.

Comment: Can I ask: whenever we see the relative adverbs like "where" , we can replace them with "preposition +which". I know the reverse of this statement can't be true and correct.for example" There is a skating school where yo can take lessons, and there is a cafe where you can enjoy lunch or dinner after skate." Can I replace "where" with "which +preposition"?

Comment: @MickeyMouse: "..the reverse of that statement can't be true.. " I don't know what you mean. The two examples you suggested are fine as they are, and would also be fine as "at which" and "in which" respectively.

Comment: I meant : Can we  substitute  relative adverb "where" for [preposition +which], whenever we saw the 'where' in our sentences. Like my examples above. I meant by saying "reverse .." is that we can't replace [preposition+which] whenever we see [where] in our sentences. Like my original example.

Comment: @MickeyMouse, you are confusing me.  Are you sure that you are using the word substitute correctly? If you substitute A for B it means that you remove B and insert A instead. The reason you can't do any substituting at all with your original example is that it contains neither **where** nor **preposition + which**. You can replace any occurrence of **in which** with **where**, and any occurrence of relative adverb **where** with **in which**.

Comment: @JavaLatte allow me to apologize for infringing on your time. I am really sorry for making you confused. I got it. Thanks so much.

Comment: @MickeyMouse:... though **when** in your original sentence is a relative adverb, and you could replace it with **at which**.

Comment: @ JavaLatte Great sample. and our choice for using "at which" instead of "on which" or "in which" is because of the verb in the dependent clause or because of the noun 'time'?